# С4430, С2238, C2065, C2039

Tags: c++

много ошибок на строках 11 и 12. Что я делаю не так? Непредвиденные лексемы перед 'токен', отсутствует спецификатор типа — предполагается int, и там дальше почему-то перед методом Read требуется "(" на строке 19, file_name и fs - необъявленные идентификаторы и т.д.

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#pragma warning
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#define D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
class MyCFile
{
private: fstream *fs;
        string *file_name;

public:
    MyCFile(string);
    MyCFile();
     MyCFile& operator=(const MyCFile&);
    MyCFile(const MyCFile&);
     string Read();//считать весь текст из файла
     void Write(char* ,long, int);// записывает с позиции опр.
     long GetPosition();//позицию указателя возвращает текущую
     ~MyCFile();
     void Seek(long);
     void Close();


};
```

Comment: *Что я делаю не так?* - используете БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ, постите текст в виде картинки, да еще jpg... и не приводите лог сборки...

Answer (score 1):

перед fstream и string нужно std:: написать